# SOAP API to get site Collection Users

Tags: user-profile, site-collection, soap, api

How can I get list of all users present in the SharePoint Site collection using SOAP API.

Is that possible? Please suggest something.
Because I have to use that URL in InfoPath form.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working in InfoPath.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for [`UserGroup.GetUserCollectionFromSite Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772702(v=office.12).aspx) of [UserGroup web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772575(v=office.12).aspx) which

> Returns information about the collection of users for the current site
>   collection.

Endpoint url: `http://site/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx?op=GetUserCollectionFromSite`

**How to invoke a SOAP request from a browser**

```
POST http://site/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/GetUserCollectionFromSite"
```

Body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUserCollectionFromSite xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Example using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) extension:

[image]

Comment: I have used your URL in browser. I can see all operation available. When I click on GetUserCollectionFromSite operation I am not able to see Users..
Is that possible to see all users in browser

Comment: Unable to find XML Data in Browser ... I need XML data because I have to user that URL as Data Connection  in InfoPath form...

Comment: For that case i usually prefer Postman Chrome extension, see my updated answer that demonstrates how to invoke this operation

Comment: But I Am not able to Use that URL in InfoPath Form Data Connection..